# How to group items by date in Yii CListView?

Tags: php, html, yii

Imagine a plain list of news items rendered by a CListView. Each news item has an 'insertDate' property that I can access via $data->insertDate. Right now, such a list would look like this rendered:

```
// example (how list is displayed now)
9-18-2012 - Stocks fell for 2nd week
9-18-2012 - Record heat for 2012
9-18-2012 - Crime down in the state
9-17-2012 - Stock woes are worrying investors
9-17-2012 - Business outlook is optimistic despite slow growth
9-16-2012 - More people moving into big cities
9-16-2012 - Stay ahead of the flu this year
```

What I want to do is display a single date header above all items that fall within that day so that the display would look more like this (below). Is there a way to tweak CListView to do this?

```
// example of what i want to do
=======News for 9/18======
Stocks fell for 2nd week
Record heat for 2012
Crime down in the state

=======News for 9/17======
Stock woes are worrying investors
Business outlook is optimistic despite slow growth

=======News for 9/16======
More people moving into big cities
Stay ahead of the flu this year
```

Comment: i think there's an extension for this, for a start [try this extension search query](http://www.yiiframework.com/search/?q=group&type=extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out this one http://groupgridview.demopage.ru/ or this http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/xdateview/ . And you can create your custom gridview basing on this two above, goodluck.